# How to fetch the particular data from Mongo subdocument in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have tried to fetch data for the particular column value in the mongo document but its displaying whole data.

Following is the mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59db2321811a592384865711"),
    "User_ID" : "demo",
    "Project_ID" : "demo-1",
    "Project_Information" : {
        "Project_Description" : "Sample",
        "Primary_Building_Type" : "Office",
        "State" : "AR",
        "Analysis_Type" : "1",
        "Project_Billing_Number" : "WY",
        "Country" : "USA",
        "Climate_Zone" : "3A",
        "Zip_Code" : "71611"
        "City" : "WA",
        "Units" : "IP"
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the following output:

```
[
    {
        "User_ID": "demo",
        "Project_Description": "Sample"
}]
```

I have tried using dot: `Project_Information.Project_Description`.The code is as below:

```
public Object[] addDemo1(String User_ID) throws Exception {
    DB db = ConnectToDB.getConnection();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    input = GetProjectStatus.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    String col = prop.getProperty("COLLECTION_PI");
    System.out.println("data is.." + col);
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(col);
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject fields2 = new BasicDBObject();
    List<DBObject> obj1 = null;
    if (User_ID != null && !User_ID.equals("") && User_ID.length() > 0) {
        obj.put("User_ID", User_ID);
        fields.put("_id", 0);
        fields.put("User_ID", 1);
        fields.put("Project_ID", 1);
        fields.append("Project_Information.Project_Description", "Project_Description");
        BasicDBObject fields1 = new BasicDBObject();
        fields1.put("User_ID", User_ID);
    }
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(obj, fields);
    System.out.println("count  is:" + cursor.count());
    obj1 = cursor.toArray();
    System.out.println("" + obj1);
    cursor.close();
    db.getMongo().close();
    return obj1.toArray();

}
```

But it displays the whole structure of `Project_Information`.

Please specify how to achieve this. Thanks for help.

Comment: -1 because you havent included any code that you have tried. How are people supposed to know what you are using, what is your query? Include that, I'll remove the -1

Comment: why is it `fields.append("Project_Information.Project_Description", "Project_Description");`
Shouldn't the second argument be `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a 2.x MongoDB Java Driver**

Here's an example using the MongoDB 2.x Java driver:

```
DBCollection collection = mongoClient.getDB("stackoverflow").getCollection("demo");

BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();

// project on "Project_Information.Project_Description"
projection.put("Project_Information.Project_Description", 1);

DBCursor documents = collection.find(filter, projection);

for (DBObject document : documents) {
    // the response contains a sub document under the key: "Project_Information"
    DBObject projectInformation = (DBObject) document.get("Project_Information");
    // the "Project_Description" is in this sub document
    String projectDescription = (String) projectInformation.get("Project_Description");

    // prints "Sample"
    System.out.println(projectDescription);

    // to return this single String value in an Object[] (as implied by your OP) just do create the Object[] like this and then return it ...
    Object[] r = new Object[] {projectDescription};

    // prints the entire projected document e.g. 
    // { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59db2321811a592384865711" }, "Project_Information" : { "Project_Description" : "Sample" } }
    System.out.println(document.toString());
}
```

**Using a 3.x MongoDB Java Driver**

Here's an example using the MongoDB 3.x Java driver:

```
    // this finds all documents in a given collection (note: no parameter supplied to the find() call) 
    // and for each document it projects on Project_Information.Project_Description
    FindIterable<Document> documents =
            mongoClient.getDatabase("...").getCollection("...")
               .find()
               // for each attrbute you want to project you must include its dot notation path and the value 1 ... 
               // this is the equivalent of specifying {'Project_Information.Project_Description': 1} in the MongoDB shell
               .projection(new Document("Project_Information.Project_Description", 1));

    for (Document document : documents) {
        // the response contains a sub document under the key: "Project_Information"
        Document projectInformation = (Document) document.get("Project_Information");
        // the "Project_Description" is in this sub document
        String projectDescription = projectInformation.getString("Project_Description");

        // prints "Sample"
        System.out.println(projectDescription);

        // to return this single String value in an Object[] (as implied by your OP) just do create the Object[] like this and then return it ...
        Object[] r = new Object[] {projectDescription};

        // prints the entire projected document e.g. { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59db2321811a592384865711" }, "Project_Information" : { "Project_Description" : "Sample" } }
        System.out.println(document.toJson());
    }
```

Comment: thanks!, but its giving error for "The method projection(Document) is undefined for the type DBCursor". where we need to define it?

Comment: @SprihaSrivastava Your use of a `DBCursor` tells me that you are using a 2.x MongoDB Java driver so I have updated the answer with an example showing how to project using the 2.x MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: Ok thanks, if I want to return as obj1 as Object[] type. How to change it to Object[] type from String please?

Comment: @SprihaSrivastava You are projecting on a single value so it seems a little odd to return that as an Object[] however ... any `String` value can be added to an `Object[]` e.g. `String s = "some string"; Object[] r = new Object[] {s};`

Answer (score 0):

Java libraries won't let you directly access using dot.

They have build in getter and setter methods.

You have not mentioned which package you are using.

Here's the query that you need:

```
db.mycol.find({},{User_ID:1,"Project_Information.Project_Description":1})
```

It will give:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db2321811a592384865711"),
    "User_ID" : "demo",
    "Project_Information" : { "Project_Description" : "Sample" }
}
```

You will have to convert the query in whatever format your package accepts.

Here's a tutorial:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i

Comment: Thanks, my output is: 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db2321811a592384865711"),
    "User_ID" : "demo",
    "Project_Information" : { "Project_Description" : "Sample" }
}

using above code in the question.

Comment: well, i am using Mongo 3.0 version, not sure if this version accepts this.